# how to efficiently utilize GPU with a huge dataset and batch size of 1 so that training the model is fast

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

Can a pytorch NN with a batch size of 1 and huge dataset be used efficiently with GPU,s or we need to increase the batch size to improve GPU utilization? How do we efficiently  utilize GPU with a huge dataset and batch size of 1 so that training the model is fast?

Comment: Increase the batch size to utilize maximum amount of memory on the GPU?

Comment: Make sure that data-loading is not a bottleneck (should be fast) and use larger number of workers in the dataloader (to parallely load the data while GPU is processing a batch).

Comment: I have taken batch = 1. Can that be a bottleneck.  Data loading is done from the dataloader and not causing trouble. The major processing time consumed is while training the model and optimizing.